# What are the available J2ME SDK using Java code?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I am a Java J2SE developer, and i want to learn J2ME to start creating mobile applications.I see i can use the default Oracle Java ME SDK. Do you know other Mobile SDks that are Java based, as i want to write Java code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse works just fine for this purpose. Have a look at [Mobile Tools for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/) (formerly known as [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/)).

From the eclipse me link:

> *EclipseME is an Eclipse plugin to help develop J2ME MIDlets. EclipseME does the "grunt work" of connecting Wireless Toolkits to the Eclipse development environment, allowing you to focus on developing your application, rather than worrying about the special needs of J2ME development.*

Answer (score 3):

IMHO Android is the way to go if you want to do java for the mobile, even better than j2me.

see [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Arguably "better" as in "a much nicer API to code against and much more powerful handsets on average". But J2ME still has a pretty huge market and those handsets can't usually run Android software, so Android is **not** a drop-in replacement for J2ME in any way.

Comment: @Joachim I was answering "Do you know other Mobile SDks that are Java based, as i want to write Java code ?"

Comment: and ignoring the part that said "I am a Java J2SE developer, and i want to learn J2ME".  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of Java ME SDK suppliers / vendors that I was able to find using Google:

- [Motorola](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/sdks/)
- [LG](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.mai.RetrieveMainPage.dev)
- [Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Java/)
- [Samsung](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3012)
- [Sony Ericsson](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3311)
- [RIM](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp)

and probably more

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans Java ME plug-in is kinda the same than Java ME SDK, but obviously with all the options Netbeans include. That's the one I use.

And if you're decided to go on with Java ME, I suggest you to have a look to [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/), in order to make nicer interfaces within the own Java Me technology.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Java for mobile and not necessarily J2ME, you can also try [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and [Blackberry](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/) development.